# adb devices show phone in debug mod but not in fastboot mod

Tags: htc-magic, linux, adb

When debugging mode adb devices , it will show my HTC magic.

But when the phone is in fastboot mod , I can't see my HTC magic in adb devices.

I am using ubuntu 10.10 , 
my /lib/udev/rules.d/11-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c01", MODE="0666", OWNER="<your user name>" #Normal HTC magic
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c02", MODE="0666", OWNER="<your user name>" #Debug & Recovery HTC MAGIC
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0fff", MODE="0666", OWNER="<your user name>" #Fastboot magic
```

Comment: I am facing same problem in my LG GT540 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the idProduct value is correct? run `lsusb` when the device is connected in fastboot mode to see the vendor id and product id and check if it matches.

Also, I think it's not supposed to show up on `adb devices` when in fastboot mode, try `fastboot devices` instead.

Comment: ohh , i get the device name already with fastboot ,  now i have a Remote Not Allow error ....

Comment: Can't help with that, have different devices, but check out this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=529167